# Why Partition Scan is not happening

Tags: database, azure-sql-database, database-partitioning

I have partitioned my table using `day` column defined as this in schema :  `day DATE`

No i am running this query :

```
select * from my_table where day={d '2023-06-07'}
```

My Query Plan is showing me this :
[image]

It's doing full scan and Number of Rows Read is very high. It not going to partition to read the data.

When i run this query :

```
SELECT
partition_id, row_count
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id = object_id('my_table');
```

it is showing me the data partioned :

```
partition_id        row_count
72057594060537856   52602
72057594060603392   18632
72057594060668928   11860
72057594060734464   11976
```

Comment: It looks like your table is partitioned correctly, but the query optimizer is not able to use the partitioning scheme to optimize your query. Could you please start by updating statistics by running the UPDATE STATISTICS command. If the statistics are out of date, the query optimizer may not be able to choose the optimal query plan.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you can you use the **PARTITION FUNCTION** and **PARTITION SCHEME**

Here I have created a table and created the **PARTITION FUNCTION** and **PARTITION SCHEME**

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pf_day_partition_my_table200(DATE)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ();

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME ps_day_partition_my_table200
AS PARTITION pf_day_partition
ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);
```

[image]
In the Partition function the range values for partitioning are not specified.
You also can provide specific range values to define how the data should be partitioned.

And partition scheme defines how the partitions defined by the partition function are distributed across filegroups in a database.
The "**ALL TO ([PRIMARY])**" part of the statement specifies that all partitions should be stored in the primary filegroup of the database.
Created the Table

```
create TABLE my_table200
(
    id INT not null,
    data VARCHAR(100),
    day DATE
);
```

[image]

Now created the Non- clustered Index.
Non-clustered index is a separate structure that improves the performance of queries by providing a quick lookup of data based on the indexed column(s). In this case, the index is created on the "day" column of the "my_table200" table.

Adding a primary key constraint (pk_my_table)  statement adds a primary key constraint to the "my_table200" table.
The "CLUSTERED" keyword specifies that the primary key constraint will create a clustered index on the "id" column.
[image]

Now I tried the query as you specified.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table200
WHERE day = {d '2023-06-07'};

SELECT
partition_id, row_count
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id = object_id('my_table200');
```

[image]
[image]